# Vectorised version of multi-dimensional outer product (`kron`)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have genearalised the outer product between a 3vector and itself to take input from a collection (NxNx3 matrix) of 3-vectors.

At the moment, my function does what I want (see example output and input below), and it looks like this. I would like to make it faster by avoiding the two `for` loops which I currently use.

```
function [rr]=OuterVec(r)

N = size(r,1);
rr = zeros(N,N,3,3);

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        rr(i,j,:,:)=kron(reshape(r(i,j,:),[1,3]),permute(r(i,j,:),[3 2 1]));
    end
end
end
```

**I/O Examples**

```
c = ones(2,2);
V(1,1,:)=[1 2 3];
u = c.*V;
```

> > OuterVec(u)
>
> ans(:,:,1,1) =
>
> ```
>  1     1
>  1     1
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,2,1) =
>
> ```
>  2     2
>  2     2
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,3,1) =
>
> ```
>  3     3
>  3     3
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,1,2) =
>
> ```
>  2     2
>  2     2
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,2,2) =
>
> ```
>  4     4
>  4     4
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,3,2) =
>
> ```
>  6     6
>  6     6
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,1,3) =
>
> ```
>  3     3
>  3     3
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,2,3) =
>
> ```
>  6     6
>  6     6
> ```
>
> ans(:,:,3,3) =
>
> ```
>  9     9
>  9     9
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to permute dimensions and apply element-wise product with singleton expansion:

```
rr = bsxfun(@times, r, permute(r, [1 2 4 3]));
```

Or, in Matlab R2016b onwards,

```
rr = r .* permute(r, [1 2 4 3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I modify this if I had two vectors instead? Say: `uv(i,j,:,:)=kron(reshape(u(i,j,:),[1,3]),permute(v(i,j,:),[3 2 1]));`

Comment: I think that's `bsxfun(@times, v, permute(u, [1 2 4 3]))` (or `v .* permute(u, [1 2 4 3])`)